# Wygwam character limit?

Tags: wygwam

Is there a character limit on Wygwam / CKEditor?

One of our clients just tried to add a very, very long entry (65k characters or so) and it spit the bit.

Perhaps PHPMemory running out as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

65k characters is just the limit of a MySQL `TEXT` column. You will need to edit the appropriate `exp_channel_data` database column (using PhpMyAdmin or similar) and change the column type to `LONGTEXT`.

Comment: Thanks Adrian! I'll try that and change the column type.