# Wygwam character limit for Cyrillic text

Tags: wygwam

I'm finding that Cyrillic text entered into a Wygwam field is truncated. Is this because there is a limit for character rendered in unicode?

Comment: Possibly. Also it might have to do with the encoding your `channel_entries` table is set for. In UTF-8, Cyrillic glyphs usually take 2 bytes of storage space, but US English glyphs only take 1 byte.

Comment: Andrew, take a look at this answer and see if it helps you: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/13714/22 Let us know if it does! I suspect it will.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a limit to the size of the table in the database. In my case the easiest solution was to add an extra text field.